# Use pdfplumber to do PDF to Excel on web page

Tags: html, python-3.x, pdf, pdfplumber

I have a question.I want use python module pdfplumber to do pdf read,and transfer file to excel，and save it.But this program doesn't seem to be very successful.Hope someone can give me some pointers

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import pdfplumber
from openpyxl import Workbook
import os


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # 獲取上傳的 PDF 文件
        uploaded_file = request.files['file']

        if uploaded_file.filename != '':
            # 保存上傳的 PDF 文件
            pdf_filename = os.path.join('uploads', uploaded_file.filename)
            uploaded_file.save(pdf_filename)

            # 提取 PDF 文本内容
            pdf_text = extract_pdf_text(pdf_filename)

            if pdf_text:
                # 創建Excel文件並寫入PDF内容
                excel_filename = os.path.join('downloads', f'{os.path.splitext(uploaded_file.filename)[0]}.xlsx')
                create_excel_file(excel_filename, pdf_text)

                return render_template('index.html', message='轉換成功', excel_link=excel_filename)
            else:
                return render_template('index.html', error='無法讀取PDF')

    return render_template('index.html')

def extract_pdf_text(pdf_filename):
    pdf_text = ''
    with pdfplumber.open(pdf_filename) as pdf:
        for page in pdf.pages:
            pdf_text += page.extract_text()

    return pdf_text

def create_excel_file(excel_filename, pdf_text):
    workbook = Workbook()
    sheet = workbook.active

    for line in pdf_text.split('\n'):
        sheet.append([line])

    workbook.save(excel_filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

result(terminal)
PS C:\python-flask> python app.py

- Serving Flask app 'app'
- Debug mode: on
  WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
- Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
  Press CTRL+C to quit
- Restarting with stat
- Debugger is active!
- Debugger PIN: 782-820-844

result (transfer file web page)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye91D.png)

I try this way,but still haven't result.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "<h1>Hello!</h1>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from waitress import serve
    serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

Comment: The index.html might also be helpful for those looking at this issue.

Comment: try to change  `pdf_text += page.extract_text()` with `pdf_text = page.extract_text()`

Comment: I try pdf_text = page.extract_text() ,still can't be useful,terminal show TemplateNotFound
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html

Comment: I checked 'index.html' ,how can i fix this problem

Comment: In `C:\python-flask`, do you have the "uploads" directory? Can also refer to the code at https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/fileuploads/ that specifies the upload directory in the app config.